# R: match row-wise from lookup and output result as 1/0

Tags: r

```
set.seed(999)
lookup <- mtcars[1:6,1:2]       #lookup table
data <- mtcars[4:7, 1:2]        #my actual data
data <- data[sample(nrow(data)),]   #shuffle row-wise

data
lookup <- tibble::rownames_to_column(lookup, "id") 
data <- tibble::rownames_to_column(data, "id")

data$matchornot <- match(data.frame(t(data)), data.frame(t(lookup)))
#Code ends

lookup
                 id  mpg cyl
1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6
2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6
3        Datsun 710 22.8   4
4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6
5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8
6           Valiant 18.1   6


data
                     mpg cyl
1 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8
2        Duster 360 14.3   8
3    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6
4           Valiant 18.1   6


My output:
                 id  mpg cyl matchornot
1 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8          1
2        Duster 360 14.3   8          1 #<--There's no Duster model in lookup, suppose to be 0
3    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6          1
4           Valiant 18.1   6          1
```

Hi, would like to find row-wise intersection of a data frame via referring to a lookup table, if there's exact match (row-wise), 1/0 is applied

thanks

*updated v1:
Apologies for not being concise enough..

The entire row have to be matched 100%. For example, if Valiant model is 99.0 mpg, your output data$matchornot for that model is "0"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data$matchornot <- is.element(data$id, lookup$id)
data$matchornot <- as.numeric(data$matchornot)
```

**Update**

```
match.id <- as.numeric(is.element(data$id, lookup$id))
match.mpg <- as.numeric(is.element(data$mpg, lookup$mpg))
data$matchornot <- match.id*match.mpg
```

Now if for instance `Valiant` has `mpg 99.0` instead of `18.1`, then the corresponding element of `match.mpg` will be `0`, thus `0` in the product.

---

See the example below where `Valiant` has `mpg = 99.0`:

```
data.v2 <- data
data.v2$mpg[which(data.v2$id == "Valiant")] <- 99.0
match.id <- as.numeric(is.element(data.v2$id, lookup$id))
match.mpg <- as.numeric(is.element(data.v2$mpg, lookup$mpg))
data.v2$matchornot <- match.id*match.mpg
```

With the following output

```
> data.v2
                 id  mpg cyl matchornot
1 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8          1
2        Duster 360 14.3   8          0
3    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6          1
4           Valiant 99.0   6          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `dplyr::left_join`

```
left_join(data, lookup, by = "id") %>%
    mutate(matchornot = ifelse(mpg.y == mpg.x & !is.na(mpg.y), 1, 0)) %>%
    select(-mpg.y, -cyl.y) %>%
    rename(mpg = mpg.x, cyl = cyl.x)
#                 id  mpg cyl matchornot
#1        Duster 360 14.3   8          0
#2           Valiant 18.1   6          1
#3 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8          1
#4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6          1
```

Or in base R using `match`

```
data$matchornot <- match(data$id, lookup$id);
data$matchornot <- ifelse(is.na(data$matchornot), 0, 1);
data;
#                 id  mpg cyl matchornot
#1        Duster 360 14.3   8          0
#2           Valiant 18.1   6          1
#3 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8          1
#4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6          1
```

---

### Update

To match all entries in `data` you can `match` concatenated row entries

```
data$matchornot <- match(
    apply(data, 1, paste0, collapse = "_"), 
    apply(lookup, 1, paste0, collapse = "_"));
data$matchornot <- ifelse(is.na(data$matchornot), 0, 1);
data;
#                 id  mpg cyl matchornot
#1 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8          1
#2    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6          1
#3           Valiant 18.1   6          1
#4        Duster 360 14.3   8          0
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort M.Evers. Updated info.

Comment: @beavis11111 Can you please update your sample data such that they reflect your updated requirements. I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @beavis11111 Ok, provided I understood you correctly, my updated solution should be what you're after. Please take a look.